# Excel VBA syntax error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to use the following code I found on the web but it stops due to a syntax error:see below

```vb
Sub TestCNR()
    Cnr 10, 4
End Sub
Sub Cnr(n, r)
    i = 1
    For j = 1 To r
        Cells(i, j).Value = j
    Next

    Do Until Finished(n, r, i)
        j = FindFirstSmall(n, r, i)
' The error occures in below line
        For k = 1 To j – 1           
            Cells(i + 1, k).Value = Cells(i, k).Value
        Next
        Cells(i + 1, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value + 1
        For k = j + 1 To r
            Cells(i + 1, k).Value = Cells(i + 1, k - 1).Value + 1
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
Function Finished(n, r, i)
    Temp = True

    For j = r To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, j).Value <> j + (n - r) Then
            Temp = False
        End If
    Next
    Finished = Temp
End Function

Function FindFirstSmall(n, r, i)
    j = r
    Do Until Cells(i, j).Value <> j + (n - r)
        j = j - 1
    Loop
    FindFirstSmall = j
End Function
```

Can someone advise cause of error please?

Comment: Remove the ** ** from `For k = 1 To j - 1`

Comment: @angelofdev I took these `**` as the OP showing us where the syntax error is... which I can replicate by pasting OP's code (without the `**`'s) in the VBE.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you're right the - isn't a -

Comment: `** **` marks replaced with a comment.

Answer (score 5):

> *[...] code I found on the web*
>
> ```
> For k = 1 To j – 1
> ```

That `–` character isn't a `-`. Don't just copy-paste code from the internet :)

```
Debug.Print Asc("–")
 150
Debug.Print Asc("-")
 45
```

`Chr$(150)` isn't recognized as a `MINUS` operator by VBA's parser: the token is invalid, hence the syntax error.

FYI these unqualified `Cells` calls are implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is; you might want to make your target sheet more explicit than that.